# Rearrange an array so that arr[i] becomes arr[arr[i]] with O(1) extra space

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

The task is to rearrange an array so that `arr[i]` becomes `arr[arr[i]]` with `O(1)` extra space.

Example:

```
2 1 3 5 4 0
```

becomes:

```
3 1 5 0 4 2
```

I can think of an `O(n²)` solution. An `O(n)` solution was presented [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-given-array-place/):

> 1. Increase every array element `arr[i]` by `(arr[arr[i]] % n)*n`.
> 2. Divide every element by `n`.

But this is very limited as it will cause buffer overflow.

Can anyone come up with an improvement upon this?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno: Probably language agnostic.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Any Language. I am just looking for an algorithm.

Comment: What makes you think there's a better solution?

Comment: The problem with the linked 'solution' is that it really requires O(n) extra space, in the form of doubling the size of each array element...

Comment: check my answer below. I am sure this works nicely

Comment: Removing my answer as it doesn't solve the problems time complexity.

Comment: I added some code - please see my updated answer. It's similar to the geeksforgeeks link in that the array elements are used to store additional information. O(n) but without the risk of overflow.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I thought the issue you raised is interesting so I started a discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903507/what-is-the-space-complexity-of-this-algorithm

Comment: @ChrisDodd: If we assume that the integers are stored as 32-bit integers and trying to have larger numbers than that will cause overflow, then there is absolutely no space increase, since the number of bits to represent each number is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the values in the array are all positive (or all negative), one way to avoid overflow could be to run the permutation cycles and use the integer sign to mark visited indexes. (Alternatively, if the array length is smaller than 2^(number of bits for one array element - 1), rather than use the sign, we could shift all the values one bit to the left and use the first bit to mark visited indexes.) This algorithm results in both less iterations and less modifications of the original array values during run-time than the algorithm you are asking to improve.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alhambra1/ar6X6/

JavaScript code:

```
function rearrange(arr){
    var visited = 0,tmp,indexes,zeroTo

    function cycle(startIx){
        tmp = {start: startIx, value: arr[startIx]}
        indexes = {from: arr[startIx], to: startIx}

        while (indexes.from != tmp.start){
            if (arr[indexes.from] == 0)
                zeroTo = indexes.to
            if (indexes.to == visited){
                visited++
                arr[indexes.to] = arr[indexes.from]
            } else {
                arr[indexes.to] = -arr[indexes.from]
            }
            indexes.to = indexes.from
            if (indexes.from != tmp.start)
                indexes.from = arr[indexes.from]
        }

        if (indexes.to == visited){
            visited++
            arr[indexes.to] = tmp.value
        } else {
            arr[indexes.to] = -tmp.value
        }
    }

    while (visited < arr.length - 1){
        cycle(visited)

        while (arr[visited] < 0 || visited == zeroTo){
            arr[visited] = -arr[visited]
            visited++
        }
    }

    return arr
}
```

Comment: Is this some kind of recursion? Recursion will take a lot of space in the program's stack for each call, so I don't think this is valid :)

Comment: Technically this still reqires O(n) extra bits of storage.

Comment: @n.m. OP asked for an improvement on the algorithm that might overflow. In my opinion, this is. (Also, technically, these O(n) bits are already available.)

Comment: @n.m. Also, to be technically correct, in all cases using this code, less than `n` bits (sometimes significantly less) are used to store visited indexes since they are only called for when the visits do not pass over the next `visited` index.

Comment: @n.m. n.m., What is the space complexity of the following algorithm: given an array of n 8-bit signed integers each equal to 7, increase each value in the array by 1? According to your comment, we can claim that the algorithm requires O(n) extra space. A more subtle example: given an array of n 8-bit signed integers, what is the space complexity of an algorithm that tests each value in the array by increasing it by 1 and then decreasing it back?

Comment: No, in this case you need these bits to represent the output of the algorithm, so no, they are not extra, they are essential to the problem itself. If you increment all numbers and then decrement them all back, than yes, you have used up extra bits that should count towards space complexity.

Comment: @n.m. While I can appreciate your point of view theoretically, I think an argument can be made that `n`, meaning the given data-set, can be viewed as either the net bits comprising the array's values, as you seem to be claiming, or the bits allocated for the array in total (assuming we're not packing bits). Bits that are part of the given data-set ought not to be counted towards an algorithm's space complexity, right?

Comment: @n.m. Care to join in on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903507/what-is-the-space-complexity-of-this-algorithm/22903582#22903582

Comment: I think here we forgot that when we have **3-bit integers** equal to 7, increasing it by 1 will result in 0, and do not increase the space requirement for each number to 4-bit. This algorithm uses the bits that's already being used in the first place to represent the number, so it's ok (see the assumption that all of them are positive). So this algorithm is using `O(1)` extra space.

Comment: I think your code is a bit more complicated than it could be. I created a Python equivalent here: http://ideone.com/6nXAAm. The code allows 0 to be inside (which seems to be the requirement in OP's question). And btw, you might need to flag your answer to moderator to remove the "community wiki" status of your answer. I see that this is not an attempt to make the answer more prevalent, but just to make it better. Note that more than 10 edits automatically convert your answer into community wiki.

Comment: @justhalf Thank you for your comments and code ideas - as far as I know, zero can be present using my code (hint: that's what my variable, "zeroTo," is for), although I like your idea of simply subtracting once more. Perhaps one reason my code looks more complicated to you is that it seeks to complete with a minimum of iterations (always less than O(2n)), avoiding a straight O(2n) which is what yours does.

Comment: You should say "less than 2n iterations" rather than "less than O(2n)", because O(2n)=O(n) and so it's the same as saying "less than O(n)", which could mean "O(log n)" or even "O(1)".

Answer (score 0):

//Traverse the array till the end.
//For every index increment the element by array[array[index] % n]. To get //the ith element find the modulo with n, i.e array[index]%n.
//Again traverse to end
//Print the ith element after dividing the ith element by n, i.e. array[i]/n

```
   class Rearrange  
{ 
       void rearrange(int arr[], int n)  
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            arr[i] += (arr[arr[i]] % n) * n; 
  
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            arr[i] /= n; 
    } 
  
    void printArr(int arr[], int n)  
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
        System.out.println(""); 
    } 
  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    { 
        Rearrange rearrange = new Rearrange(); 
        int arr[] = {6, 4, 9, 2, 5, 7}; 
        int n = arr.length; 
  
        System.out.println("Given Array is :"); 
        rearrange.printArr(arr, n); 
  
        rearrange.rearrange(arr, n); 
  
        System.out.println("Modified Array is :"); 
        rearrange.printArr(arr, n); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi! I think your solution would be more helpful if you explained your code and reasons for going about your answer