# Space Complexity and Modifying the Data Set

Tags: algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

What is the space complexity of the following algorithm?

Given an array of `n` 32-bit signed integers, where each value is positive and less than two to the power of 30, negate all values in the array, then negate all values in the array a second time.

The question arose for me out of a discussion in the comment section here: [Rearrange an array so that arr[i] becomes arr[arr[i]] with O(1) extra space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843793/rearrange-an-array-so-that-arri-becomes-arrarri-with-o1-extra-space/22850982#22850982)

I am specifically interested in different opinions and definitions. I think subtle distinctions and definitions may be missing sometimes in some stackoverflow discussions on this subject.

Comment: To the downvoter/s, please let me know if there is anything you would appreciate changed in my question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I also misunderstood the question, so perhaps I can shed light on the downvoters. Your question sounds as if you're asking us to analyze the algorithm that you outlined. However, it seems as if you wanted us to think of the optimal algorithm, and analyze it instead. What you called "algorithm", was actually the "problem to solve".

Comment: @vivekmaharajh If I understand you correctly then you were correct in the first instance - I am interested in expert views about the definition and role of the data set in space complexity analysis, which I tried to elicit through my example algorithm.

Comment: @paxdiablo was spot on with the "added" space requirements. The way the question was asked, "added" was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: This is not a question in itself then, since the answer requires the context which is in the other question you linked. This needs to be addressed in the original question, not here. Otherwise, this would just be an A/B question.

Comment: @justhalf Thank you for your comment. I think this question can stand on its own - I provided the link to the other question simply as an explanation of why I am asking. What is an "A/B question?"

Comment: Sorry, it should be XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: To the person/people considering closing - could you please explain why? Is there something you would like to see changed/improved in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Space complexity usually refers to the *added* space requirements for an algorithm, over and above the original data set itself. In this case, the original data set is the `n` 32-bit signed integers, so you're only concerned with extra storage above that.

In that case, that extra storage is is basically nothing, which translates to constant `O(1)` space complexity.

If you were required to create a *separate* array (negated, then negated again), it would be `O(n)` since the space required is in proportion to the original data set.

But, since you're doing the negations in-place, that's not the case.

Comment: Thank you for you answer - I think reasonable people might disagree as to the definition of "data set." If you like, please see in the comments here the reason for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843793/rearrange-an-array-so-that-arri-becomes-arrarri-with-o1-extra-space/22850982#22850982

Comment: @גלעד ברקן, then reasonable people would be wrong :-) For example, bubble, insertion and selection sorts all have a worst case space complexity of O(1), something that wouldn't be possible if it included the original data set. Including the original data set in the space complexity analysis would be akin to including the setup time of the unsorted array in time complexity. The cost of the array data (and setup time to create it) is irrelevant as far as the algorithm itself is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two different, though related, things: computer-theoretic space complexity of an algorithm, and practical memory requirements of a program.

Algorithms in computer science are normally not formulated in terms of integers of certain predefined size which is imposed by currently predominant computer architectures. If anything, they are *parameterized* by integer size. So "given an array of n 32-bit signed integers" should be replaced with "given an array of n k-bit signed integers".

Now if all integers of the input array are actually `m<k` bit wide, and all integers of the output array are also known to be `m<k` bit wide, and nothing else *outside your algorithm* imposes `k` bit wide integers, then sneaking `k` in the problem description is just cheating in order to make your complexity look better then it actually is. Likewise, saying "signed" if both input and output data is supposed to be positive is cheating.

Real-life programs don't have complexity, they have memory requirements. It is perfectly fine to say that your program does not use any extra memory if it only temporarily uses otherwise unused sign bits of your array elements. Just don't act surprised when one fine day you discover you have too large an array and you must pack it, so that it no longer has any unused bits. That is, you are reusing your algorithm in a different program with a different data representation, one that does not have any spare bits. Then you are forced to recall that the added space complexity of your algorithm is actually O(n).

Comment: Thanks for answering n.m. Just for the record, I never claimed to take any position on this and I never confused any issues - I just asked questions. I am far from an expert and was hoping to hear the experts discuss it. I know what you are saying about "computer-theoretic space complexity of an algorithm." I'll be interested to read more opinions should the answer get any.

Comment: By the way, you didn't seem to directly answer the question on this post (what is the space complexity of the algorithm above). If I understand you correctly, then I would imagine you saying, O(n); and it is interesting for me to see at least one seemingly contrary opinion from someone with quite a solid reputation on SO.

Comment: Let me try again. If you are saying you have 32-bit signed integers, you are not describing an algorithm. Not an algorithm normally discussed in the context of complexity theory anyway. You are describing a particular implementation or a family of implementations, arbitrarily constrained by some silly technology limitation. I don't even know how I should determine its complexity, *and why*, given that I can work with k-bit integers just as easily and obtain more general results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested in **space** complexity, the only relevant part of the question is:

> "an array of n 32-bit signed integers"

From the above, the answer is pretty straightforward - **O(n)**

This whole blurb:

> negate all values in the array, then negate all values in the array a
>   second time

only affects the **time** complexity, which seems like a poorly crafted distraction in a homework assignment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - actually you can see in the comments here the reason for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843793/rearrange-an-array-so-that-arri-becomes-arrarri-with-o1-extra-space/22850982#22850982